# angularjs - keeping the view up to date

Tags: angularjs

I really am banging my head on a brick wall, have been for hours and hours....

I have a controller which gets a list of objects stored in a PouchDB via a factory which uses an angularjs promise to return the answer as it's an asynchronous request outside the flow of the angularjs app.  This works fine and returns the objects.

I then have another controller which uses an external rest API to carry out a search for more objects, on the results screen I have an "add" button which adds an object to PouchDB.

My problem is that no matter what I try, what tutorials I follow, what answers I read I cannot get the first list of objects to update when new objects are added.

Does anyone have any idea what I should be doing here?  Even if it's sensible?  Is there a better way of doing this?  Nested controllers maybe?

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: It must be a problem with the code. That's where I would look for the bug.

Comment: I'm afraid that without any actual code we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks both.  I've tried to create this Plunker which is a slimmed down copy http://plnkr.co/edit/2qJc3HEDN7kOd6InKOec BUT I can't even get this working, not it doesn't yet have the second controller to add a value, will get this added....

Comment: Fixed the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3wh8boPJlgJfH4lFQ8G?p=preview)

Comment: why the -1 on the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to tell without knowing more about your code, but a common mistake that happens is not being mindful of the different scopes that angular creates.  You can use the chrome extension [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to debug your scopes.  For simple debugging I usually set a window property to my scope in the controller (i.e. `window.SC1 = $scope;`) and check out the values in the console.

Specifically since a second controller is updating your objects it doesn't have access to the list of objects created in your other controller unless the scope is a child scope (i.e. html of your second controller is inside the html of your first controller).  Even in that case if you set a value on the child scope the change breaks the inheritance and the new value is not propagated to the parent, though you can manipulate inherited values such as arrays and objects by modifying the existing object (i.e. `$scope.objects.push(newObject);` or `$scope.obj.property = "value"`, but not `$scope.obj = newObject;`.

The more angular way to do this is to create a service that is a singleton and maintains your list of data.  You can inject that into any controller you want and get the same values and call functions on the service.

```
angular.module("MyApp").service("objService", function() {
    this.objects = [];
    this.getObjects = function() {
        // ... code to get first list of objects
    };
    this.updateObjects = function() {
        // ... code called by your second controller to update list here
    };
    this.getObjects(); // get objects when first injection occurs
);

angular.module("MyApp").controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, objService) {
    $scope.objService = objService;
};
```

[***This plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBCB0tPCIorhfQpb5p8m?p=preview) shows that the inherited list is used in Ctrl2 until it sets the value on the child scope, breaking the inheritance.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I've updated the plnkr to http://plnkr.co/edit/jtFNs5FbrDBLlyZ5TATn?p=preview but cannot get the template to display the data returned by the promise.  Any ideas on how to get this working?  I've been at this problem for hours....  Cheers.

Comment: Your service is setting a locally scoped object variable, but not a property on the service.  Change `var objects = [];` to `this.objects = [];` (and update your service to use `this.objects`) and it works.